# Retrieve PerformanceCounterCategories in another language

Tags: c#, performancecounter

When I display a list of all `PerformanceCounterCategories`, I receive a list in Dutch since that's my OS's language. Is it possible to retrieve the English list?

```
private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var cats = new List<PerformanceCounterCategory>(PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories());

        foreach (var name in cats.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryName)) {
            Console.WriteLine(name.CategoryName);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Edit:
Adding to this, is there a list of possible Categories and their counters online? I've been searching high and low and haven't stumbled upon an actual list yet.

So far the only thing I've found is [this](http://blogs.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/angus/2008/11/net-performance-counters-monitoring-resource-utilization/) article, which leads to a list of categories.
However, since it doesn't give any info on the category itself, I already received an exception stating the category doesn't exist when I use

```
var temp = new PerformanceCounterCategory("IP");
Console.WriteLine(temp.CategoryHelp);
```

Comment: It is selected by Thread.CurrentCulture.  Don't get your hopes up.

Comment: Perhaps I am approaching from the wrong direction. Basically I want to look trough the `Counters` of some `Categories` to see if there is interesting information to display in my program. Right now I'm only using data from the `Network Interface` Category. I wanted to display all (english) category names so I could choose from that list and see what values I can obtain. Should I approach this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it appearantly uses `Thread.CurrentCulture` you can't specify the language to retrieve everything in. It might be possible to install the English language pack and change your `CurrentCulture`, but I haven't followed that possibility.

Instead, someone with an English OS provided me with his [result](http://pastebin.com/9gHNeLYD) of the code above and I'll be using that as a reference to hardcode English categories, rather than Dutch. English seems to work just fine for me so I'm guessing it's standard on every machine.

I haven't found actual documentation on the categories yet, but by using common sense I was able to combine [these](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960027.aspx) technet articles with the appropriate category as displayed in the list linked above.

An example to make sure it works:

```
 var temp = new PerformanceCounter("IPv4", "Datagrams/sec");
 console.WriteLine(temp.CategoryName);

 while (true) {
      float total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
              total += temp.NextValue();
      }
      Console.WriteLine(total);
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
 }
```

Provides me with a steady stream of data, even though the documentation on Technet only specified the category as 'IP Object' without making a distinction between 'IPv4' and 'IPv6'.

If someone actually finds a solid way to fix the original issue (displaying all categories in English, despite the host system's preferences) just add it as an answer and I'll accept that instead.

Edit:
The solution by changing the `CurrentCulture`:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            var cats = new List<PerformanceCounterCategory>(PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories());
            foreach (var name in cats.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryName)) {
                Console.WriteLine("en-US: " + name.CategoryName);
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
            cats = new List<PerformanceCounterCategory>(PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories());
            foreach (var name in cats.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryName)) {
                Console.WriteLine("nl-NL: " + name.CategoryName);
            }
```